# Localize clndr in a browserify bundle

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I use the clndr js to generate a calendar element (http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/). On the github page under internationalization they say that moment.js localization is used. Thing is, I bundle my files with browserify and clndr has an UMDefinition. Moment.js and clndr are both installed with NPM, thus available with `require('moment')` and `require('clndr')`. Now here's the thing:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var clndr = require('clndr');
var $ = require('jquery');

moment.locale('de', require('moment/locales/de'));
clndr = $('.some').clndr({//some options});
```

This results in a clndr configured in english, because clndr is requiring its own version of moment.js. According to the docs on the clndr github page, there is no possibility to pass a moment instance as option on initialization and no option to alter the locales variable on the moment.js instance used by clndr.

If I try to add the clndr script to the noParse option of browserify, it results in a error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'`. As buildsystem I'm using gulp, you can find the code here: https://github.com/maxomedia/mxm-gulp. Options passed to browserify are: `{noParse: [require.resolve('jquery'), require.resolve('clndr')]}`.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?